# I have a different date format like 20-Mar-2015 to 30-Mar-2015 in a column in sql. i need to split it in two different columns in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Convert date format in two columns. Please help...thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you sql will useful to you.

```
  eg:- SELECT SUBSTRING(date_column,1,11) AS date_1, 
        SUBSTRING(date_column,16,27) AS date_2;
```

Here date_column='20-Mar-2015 TO 30-Mar-2015'

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('20-Mar-2015 TO 30-Mar-2015',1,11) AS date_1, 
 SUBSTRING('20-Mar-2015 TO 30-Mar-2015',16,27) AS date_2;
```

Thank you.

Comment: that would be my pleasure ......thanku very much and can you also tell me how to convert the same date in integer

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(STR_TO_DATE('20-Mar-2015','%d-%M-%Y') ,UNSIGNED INTEGER); like these you can covert.